# Optimum frequency estimation over a Rayleigh fading channel

Tags: signal-analysis

This question comes from the book "Autonomous Software-Defined Radio Receivers for Deep Space Applications"[1](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/monograph/series9/Descanso9_Full_rev2.pdf).

The chapter 4.1.3 is "Optimum Frequency Estimation over a Rayleigh Fading Channel". The equation (4-11) is shown below.

$$ P(r_{c} | A, \Delta f, \theta_{c}) = C_{0} e^{1(1/2\sigma^{2})Z}$$
where $C_{0}$ is a constant, and $Z$ and $Y$ are defined as in Eqs. (4-3) and (4-4). Since A is now a complex random variable, the $Z$ can be rewritten as
$$Z = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \lvert r_{c} [k]\rvert^2 - 2Re(YAe^{-j\theta_{c}}) + \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \lvert A \rvert^2 $$

The first terms in Eq.(4-12) do not depend on A. Averaging the conditional pdf in Eq.(4-11) over $A$, assuming the magnitude of $A$ is Rayleigh distributed and its phase is uniformly distributed, we obtain

$$ P(r_{c} | \Delta f, \theta_{c}) = C_{3} exp(\frac{C_{4}}{2\sigma^{2}} |Y|^2)$$

where $C_3$ and $C_4$ are constants.

The point missing here is how to do the avaraging for $A$. What I know is that I should do two integration for A, one is the magnitude of $A$ and the other is the $\theta_{A}$. My question is how to do the integration for magnitude of $A$. Thanks.